# SSIS RDS - Dynamic connection to S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssis, amazon-rds

We had SSIS packages that were using File System and we are planning to change it to use S3 buckets . So used a third party tool - `Zappysys` for taking care of this task to access / move / process with S3 buckets . It was working fine.

We are also having a plan to move `SSIS packages to RDS Server` - then we started checking and it showed up a lot of tasks which isn't supported in the RDS - like script tasks or script components.

We did change or found a solution to handle those logic by avoiding script tasks or components.

Now - we have the hurdle of connecting `SSIS RDS packages to S3 buckets` - which are dynamic by env and by client.

Would like to know if there are services that can take care of this from the `SSIS` packages which are in RDS server or does AWS provide option to open up to use third party tools.

Searching for the details but couldn't find a solution.